# passing value of selected value of dropdownlist to another in one php file

Tags: php, ajax

i have a php file i have three dropdown in one php file like region province district so based on selecting region the provinces should be shown and based on the province the district should be shown so i want to implement these in one php file how to do that i can do it in different php file but i want to do it in one php file and  the problem is that i can't pass the first dropdownlist value to the secand using ajax i want this in ajax.
if any one help me that will be highly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what i usually do in php/ajax for region - province:

jQuery code:

```
$('#idRegion').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('#idProvince').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }else{

        var idRegione = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('index.php',
                {
                    option: "com_spin",
                    controller: "guest",
                    task: "getProvincieByRegionId",
                    idRegione: idRegione
                },
                function(json){
                    $('#idProvince').html(json.html);

                }   
        );
        $('#idProvince').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

PHP code:

```
function getProvincieByRegionId() {
    Zend_Loader::loadClass ( 'Zend_Json' );
    $idRegione = JRequest::getVar ( "idRegione" );
    $modelProvince = new Spin_lkpprovincia ();
    $provincie = $modelProvince->getElencoProvinciePerRegione ( $idRegione );
    $html = "<option value=''>Selezionare una voce</option>";
    foreach ( $provincie as $provincia ) {
        $html .= "<option value='" . $provincia ['idProvincia'] . "'>" . $provincia ['nome'] . "</option>";
    }
    $json = array (
                success => "OK", 
                html => $html );

    $json = Zend_Json::encode ( $json );
    echo $json;
    die ();
}
```

You can use this as a starting point

Comment: thanks bro is it posible just using ajax it mean's passing value of dropdownlist in one php file using ajax

Comment: This is done through ajax: the jQuery code calls the php code (you have to adapt it of course, it's just an example)

Comment: actually i m new to php and mysql and i don't know about jquery and json so there for i have code in php and ajax that will be better but thanks for quick response i really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you mean about one PHP file but this is the code I use for dynamically populating sub select boxes. Basically on select box change grab the ID and do Ajax via jQuery to get JSON response of cities and populate dropdown.

I use this code for populating a select box of cities (from one PHP file) based on the country you have selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){      

$('#country').change(function(){ //any select change on the dropdown with id country trigger this code         $("select[id$=cities] > option").remove(); //first of all clear select items
    var country_id = $('#country').val();  // here we are taking country id of the selected one.
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "home/get_cities/"+country_id, //here we are calling our user controller and get_cities method with the country_id

    success: function(cities) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
    {
       $.each(cities,function(id,city) //here we're doing a foeach loop round each city with id as the key and city as the value
       {
          var opt = $('<option />'); // here we're creating a new select option with for each city
          opt.val(id);
          opt.text(city);
          $('#cities').append(opt); //here we will append these new select options to a dropdown with the id 'cities'
       });
    }

  });

  });
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

You could post the data instead if you wanted to. In the PHP you would do something like this:

```
function get_cities($country){
    $this->load->model('cities_model');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
    echo(json_encode($this->cities_model->get_cities($country)));
}
```

I wrote a post on this here: http://theninthnode.com/2011/01/dropdown-filtering-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/